# HTTP Basic Authentication in JBoss 4?

Tags: authentication, jboss

How can I enable HTTP Basic Authentication in JBoss 4 for a specific web application?

Having a fixed username/password will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this process
http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SecureAWebApplicationInJBoss

Summary:

- You add a security domain to login-config.xml
- You modify web.xml and jboss-web.xml in your war file to enable authentication using the security domain